# AWS Lambda Event for a set of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible to trigger a AWS Lambda function once a set of files has been uploaded to AWS S3. For example, if and only if file `A`, `B`, and `C` have been uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I've found, the only way I've found to do it is to send a notification file once the others are complete, so create `A`, `B` and `C` then create `files.complete` - I usually pass it the file names for the params.Body.  You can then [S3.listObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) on your bucket (the bucket name is passed in the event data) to get the names and iterate through that list to access them.